# How to access a Vue route directly

Tags: mod-rewrite, vue.js, routes, single-page-application, vue-router

I'm creating my first [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) application.

I want to use the history mode in my Vue router, so I don't have to use hashbang URLs e.g. `localhost:8080/#/login`.

So, I set the mode to history like so, which works:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [...]
})
```

My routes now show as `localhost:8080/login`. However, I can't directly access the login page using this URL, as when I refresh the current page or try to type that route directly into the browser's address bar and hit enter, I get the following error:

> Cannot GET /login

According to the [Vue documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations), I am supposed to configure my server to allow for this. They suggest, for my setup, configuring Apache and use a `mod_rewrite`.

So, I created an `.htaccess` file which contains the following `mod_rewrite` declaration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I get the same error when I try to load `localhost:8080/login` directly.

Am I missing something? Can somebody please help get me over the line with this one?

My application's directory structure looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A .htaccess file is a configuration file for an Apache webserver. `localhost:8080` is a dev server and is not run by Apache, so the `.htaccess` file is not used there.

The dev server should pick up the url automatically. When it does not, the most likely culprit is a base url or public path not set correctly, or set to the production variant. For example, if you set it to `/app/`, you have to access `localhost:8080/app/login` to reach your login page. Since the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set, you can set the public path to `/` for the development server while still keeping a custom public path for a production build.